# Grouping time series data in R using cyclic values of a column

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I have a daily dataset that needs to needs to be grouped based on the cyclic value of one column. I wish to add another column that contains the grouping identifier. For example I have this set of data

```
YEAR = c(1900, 1900, 1900, 1901,1901, 1901, 1901, 1902, 1902, 1902, 1903)
CS = c("SUM", "SUM", "SUM", "SUM", "SPR", "SPR", "SPR",  "SPR", "SPR", "SPR", "SPR")
DAS = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3,1, 2, 3, 4)


mydt <- data.table (YEAR, CS, DAS)

    YEAR  CS DAS
 1: 1900 SUM   1
 2: 1900 SUM   2
 3: 1900 SUM   3
 4: 1901 SUM   4
 5: 1901 SPR   1
 6: 1901 SPR   2
 7: 1901 SPR   3
 8: 1902 SPR   1
 9: 1902 SPR   2
10: 1902 SPR   3
11: 1903 SPR   4
```

I want to add another column that contains grouping based on the value of DAS, like this:

```
    YEAR  CS DAS     GRP
 1: 1900 SUM   1 1900SUM
 2: 1900 SUM   2 1900SUM
 3: 1900 SUM   3 1900SUM
 4: 1901 SUM   4 1900SUM
 5: 1901 SPR   1 1901SPR
 6: 1901 SPR   2 1901SPR
 7: 1901 SPR   3 1901SPR
 8: 1902 SPR   1 1902SPR
 9: 1902 SPR   2 1902SPR
10: 1902 SPR   3 1902SPR
11: 1903 SPR   4 1902SPR
```

Obviously, GRP is just a concatenation of YEAR and CS, although any identifier, say group number, will do. Grouping is based on when the value of DAS returns to 1. I used a for-loop to do this and it worked well

```
group <- function(df) {
    for (i in 1: nrow(df)) {
        if (df$DAS[i]== 1) {
            nval<- paste0(df$YEAR[i], df$CS[i])
        }
        df$GRP[i] <- nval
    }
    df
}
```

My issue is that it is very slow when used with couple of millions of rows. Is there a way to achieve it in a much faster way?

**UPDATE**
As pointed by colemand77, the grouping is not entirely based on the combination of YEAR and CS, rather based on when the value of DAS returns to 1. There are cases when the value of YEAR and CS are different yet they still belong to the same cycle of DAS, hence belong to one group.

Comment: data tables don't get automatically faster. Please go through the introduction and reference semantics vignettes [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944). What you're looking for is `mydt[, GRP := .GRP, by=c("YEAR", "CS")]` - `.GRP` is a special inbuilt variable.

Comment: Given your updated comment... Is there any logic (date, etc) that determines when the group changes, or is it just DAS returning to 1?  Is DAS always the same sequence? Always 1:4 for example, or sometimes 1:5, etc?

Comment: DAS is always a sequence of positive integer from 1 to n. Thus, n could be any positive integer. In my data, one cycle corresponds to one cropping - from sowing to harvesting. DAS actually counts the days-after-sowing which starts from 1 (sowing) and terminates when the crop is dead or harvested. Unfortunately, a cropping may start in December and harvested in May of the following year. The daily data for several years are dumped in one long time series. Being said, YEAR and Cropping Season is not a good grouping variable. In my opinion, the only way to group the data is when DAS returns to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, just to highlight Arun's answer:

```
mydt[, GRP := .GRP, by=c("YEAR", "CS")]
```

but also point out that your GRP in the above is not a concatenation of the `YEAR` and `CS` as you say... if that's just a misprint then Arun's comment is the correct one.  If it is not, then you may need to restate as Arun's answer will give unexpected results.

Try the following, haven't timed it. the ifelse might not be as fast as possible, but in quick fashion best I could do.  If its slow let me know and we'll re-hash it:

```
mydt[DAS == 1,GRP := .GRP, by = DAS][,GRP2 := cumsum(ifelse(is.na(GRP),0,GRP))]
```

Comment: Thanks Arun and colemand77 for the reply. the value of GRP, as an example was the concatenation of the value of Year and CS when DAS is 1. Irregardless of the value of YEAR and CS, the grouping should correspond to when DAS starts with 1 up to the row before DAS has a value of 1 again.

Comment: Ah! That IS an interesting question.  I haven't run into this before, so let me think about it and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @User9999 - take a look at the above and let me know if you get any performance improvement.

Comment: Thanks colemand77, it worked great. It took less than a second to execute with 7000 rows data, much better than the for loop which took 25 seconds. Thanks for all the help, appreciate it much.

Comment: Awesome. Behold the other-worldly greatness that is data.table.